# In visual expression builder in data flow how do i find median

Tags: azure-data-factory

how do i find median using expression builder in Azure Data Factory - Data Flow

There is "avg", "min", "max" etc but nothing for median.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Median is not available as an aggregate function, so there's no Median function in  Data Factory Data.

May you can use the Expression Builder to create a new expression to get the median by yourself.

Reference these document:

1. [Mapping Data Flow Expression Builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-expression-builder)
2. [Data transformation expressions in Mapping Data Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. But How do you write custom median function?